# Force single JSON property to always serialize while DefaultValueHandling is Ignore

Tags: c#, json.net

If one serializes JSON with `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`, so that the only properties serialized are non-default values, is it still possible to force one or more properties to always serialize? This would be a nice feature for when you have a JSON doc that is human readable or editable, and only a property or two really need to be discoverable, while for many others its still preferrable to only display if they are actually set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also [specify the default value handling for every property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_DefaultValueHandling.htm) with the `JsonProperty` attribute. And if you have default value handling specified globally and per property as well, the property's own attributed value takes precedence over the global setting.

```
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]
    public bool SomeFlagYouAlwaysWantToSee { get; set; }
```

Comment: To make your answer more complete, you might include a link to the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_DefaultValueHandling.htm) or a code sample showing how `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling. Include)]` is applied.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the suggestion, will keep it in mind

Comment: Any similar feature for `System.Text.Json`?...